# Date Difference in MySQL in Minutes

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I need to find the time difference in Hours for the following Dates in MySQL - Can i use Datediff functions?

2014-01-01 07:27:21 and 2014-02-01 11:29:00

I tried using `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2014-01-01 07:27:21','2014-01-01 11:29:00')` but apparently MySQL is giving an error.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: I tried Using DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2014-01-01 07:27:21','2014-01-01 11:29:00') but apparently MySQL is giving an error.

Comment: Top Google result for the title: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/163-how-to-calculate-the-interval-between-two-dates-or-times-in-mysql/ answers this succinctly.

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(From_unixtime(q.paid_date)),(From_unixtime(q.closed_date)))

Answer (score 6):

**Time difference in minutes:**

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(date1,date2))/60) AS diff
```

Example:

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff('2014-01-01 11:29:00','2014-01-01 07:27:21'))/60) AS diff
```

Result:

```
242
```

**Time difference in hours:**

```
SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(date1,date2))/60/60) AS diff
```

if you need number of hours with fractions then remove ROUND.